# How to PostgreSQL full join: counting number of events by day

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to count the number of accidents happened and resolved in a given day. The data, stored as 'Accidents' looks something like below. Each accidents that happened are assigned unique accident_issue ID, and employer ID of who solved it. Note that some accidents are not resolved in the same day that it happened, and that there are some accidents that happened at the same time.

```
INSERT INTO Accidents (empid, accident_issue, accident_date, resolved_date) VALUES
('abcd', 'a49b0a4k', '3/12/19 13:25', '3/12/19 13:37'),
('abcd', 'ao3jbvna', '2/1/19 21:16', '2/1/19 21:19'),
('abcd', 'g4b04kcd', '12/12/18 20:37', '12/12/18 21:34'),
('abcd', 'hk9502jb', '12/10/18 21:09', '12/10/18 21:13'),
('abcd', 'cj9rj4vb', '11/30/18 19:44', '11/30/18 19:49'),
('abcd', 'd948mafg', '11/24/18 19:53',  '11/26/18 19:55'),
('abcd', 'mkgiud84', '11/24/18 12:48',  '11/25/18 14:37'),
('abcd', 'it93hvmv', '11/24/18 12:48',  '11/25/18 15:29'),
('efgh', '94jbniv4', '5/17/18 19:56', '5/17/18 20:11'),
('efgh', '5k0bnck5', '4/13/18 15:07', '4/13/18 15:13'),
('efgh', 'mborj3hf', '2/28/18 21:32', '2/28/18 21:51'),
('efgh', 'vkrok4mn', '2/21/18 16:19', '2/21/18 16:35'),
('efgh', '2ivj39cn', '2/20/18 22:01', '2/20/18 22:06'),
('efgh', '0virj3mv', '2/20/18 16:21', '2/20/18 16:23'),
('efgh', 'x20xzn93', '2/9/18 21:16', '2/10/18 21:30'),
('efgh', '49jcn3k5', '2/6/18 19:35', '2/8/18 22:36');
```

I want the query result to have the number of accidents assigned and resolved by each employers by day.

My initial idea was to first count number of accidents and number of those resolved per day separately, and full join the two table.
This is the code that I have been working so far.

```
SELECT 
    a.empid, 
    a.date, 
    a.number_of_accidents, 
    b.number_resolved
FROM 
    (SELECT A1.empid, A1.accident_issue, to_char(accident_date::date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as date,
              count(accident_date) as number_of_accidents
     FROM Accidents as A1
       GROUP BY A1.empid, A1.accident_issue
     ) AS a
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT B1.empid, B1.accident_issue, to_char(resolved_date::date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as date,
              count(resolved_date) as number_resolved
     FROM Accidents as B1
       GROUP BY B1.empid, B1.accident_issue
     ) AS b
    ON a.date = b.date
    GROUP BY a.empid, a.date
```

When run separately, the two table a and b seems to return what I want, but when put together, for some reason the output gets corrupted and produce multiple duplicate rows.

I want the result to look something like below

```
| empid |    date   | number_of_accidents | number_solved |
|-------|-----------|---------------------|---------------|
| abcd  |  11/24/18 |           3         |       0       |
| abcd  |  11/25/18 |           0         |       2       |
| abcd  |  2/1/19   |           1         |       1       |
| abcd  |  3/12/19  |           1         |       1       |
| efgh  |  2/20/18  |           2         |       2       |
| efgh  |  2/21/18  |           1         |       1       |
```

What seems to be the problem, and am I heading the right direction?
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Could you post what your current output looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregate by employee and day in the subqueries and full join them on common day and employee.

```
SELECT coalesce(o.empid, r.empid) empid,
       coalesce(o.day, r.day) date,
       o.count number_of_accidents,
       r.count number_resolved
       FROM (SELECT a.empid,
                    date_trunc('day', a.accident_date) day,
                    count(*) count
                    FROM accidents a
                    GROUP BY a.empid,
                             date_trunc('day', a.accident_date)) o
            FULL JOIN (SELECT a.empid,
                              date_trunc('day', a.resolved_date) day,
                              count(*) count
                              FROM accidents a
                              GROUP BY a.empid,
                                       date_trunc('day', a.resolved_date)) r
                      ON r.empid = o.empid
                         AND r.day = o.day;
```

Comment: What purpose does coalesce function serve in 'coalesce(o.empid, r.empid) empid', and 'coalesce(o.day, r.day) date' serve? My quick research suggests that coalesce function returns the first non-null value, but there shouldn't be any null in either empid or day. Also, your code returns 'null' when there are no accidents happened or resolved in a day. How do I change that to 0?

Comment: @kunichi_kimura: Yes there can be nulls as it's a full join, so it's possible a value only exists on one "side". To get all days (you're interested in) you need to create a set of all days (you're interested in) e.g. by using `generate_series` and left join to that. There are a lot of questions dealing with that. If you have trouble with that I suggest you ask a new question. Don't forget to tell exactly what the set of days you want should look like.